# Apex Line Area chart is not getting displayed on the page in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am stuck on a page where i am not able to display the charts on the page.

To make it simplify what I have done is, here is the code sandbox:
I see there an error in console about the data, I am not sure about it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-snyder-bckoq

I want to display the chart like this (as an example), but I am not able to display on the code sandbox

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of series is not aligned with ApexCharts.
You need to transform the data to match with ApexChart format.

Please see the changes in the codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-dew-eztod?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```js
options: {
    // X axis labels
    xaxis: {
        type: 'date',
        categories: ["2021-05-04", "2021-05-05", "2021-05-07"]
    },
},
series: [
    {
        name: "total",
        data: [2, 2, 1],
    },
    {
        name: "pending",
        data: [0, 1, 0],
    },
    {
        name: "approved",
        data: [2, 1, 1],
    },
    {
        name: "rejected",
        data: [0, 0, 0],
    },
],
```

**Transform data to fit ApexChart**

```js
const data = {
  "2021-05-04": {
    total: 2,
    pending: 0,
    approved: 2,
    rejected: 0,
  },
  "2021-05-05": {
    total: 2,
    pending: 1,
    approved: 1,
    rejected: 0,
  },
  "2021-05-07": {
    total: 1,
    pending: 0,
    approved: 1,
    rejected: 0,
  },
};

const xaxis = {
  type: "date",
  categories: Object.keys(data).map((key) => key), // ['2021-05-04', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-07']
};

let statusObj = [];
for (const dataValue of Object.values(data)) { // get the values from keys '2021-05-04', '2021-05-05' ...

  // loop the values, e.g. 1st loop: { total: 2, pending: 0, approved: 2, rejected: 0, }
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataValue)) {

    // take 'total' as example, find if statusObj already has { name: 'total', data: [x] }, e.g. statusObj = { name: 'total', data: [1] }
    const existingStatusIndex = Object.keys(statusObj).find(
      (sKey) => statusObj[sKey].name === key
    );

    // if yes, return the index of it
    if (existingStatusIndex) {
      // add new data value to existing data object. e.g. { name: 'total', data: [1, 2] }
      statusObj[existingStatusIndex].data.push(value);
      continue;
    }

    // if no, create a new object and add it to statusObj
    statusObj.push({
      name: key,
      data: [value],
    });
  }
}
```

Output:

```
xaxis {
  type: 'date',
  categories: [ '2021-05-04', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-07' ]
}
statusObj [
  { name: 'total', data: [ 2, 2, 1 ] },
  { name: 'pending', data: [ 0, 1, 0 ] },
  { name: 'approved', data: [ 2, 1, 1 ] },
  { name: 'rejected', data: [ 0, 0, 0 ] }
]
```

Comment: thank you. but now the thing is that the series data needs to be dynamic. meaning it will be coming from the API. In that case how yeah? even with the x-axis dates

Comment: I think it is a different set of question of how to transform data to fit ApexChart but anyway I updated the answer. I don't know how much you know about iterating the object so i added the comments. Please upvote the answer if it is what you want.

Comment: thank a lot. one last question, shall all the function will be inside the methods or where? can please help to update here 

https://codesandbox.io/s/small-dew-eztod?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: depends on your code structure, i think you can put it in method if there is the only place you use it.
 if you find you are using it anywhere else, may consider to use mixin. 
if you have service class for fetching the data, do it there, so when you dispatch and get back the state, the data is transformed.

Comment: It will be really helpful if can update here :  https://codesandbox.io/s/small-dew-eztod?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: updated. but you are seeking too much which is far beyond the question already. and this flow may not apply to yours because you have async operation to fetch the data first.